# how to fetch values from xml file by using xdocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have an xmfile file shown below where I have to get all nodes values `CIName,Type,Status,FriendlyName,AccountNo` . I was trying to get result by using `XDocument` with no success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RetrievedeviceListResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaRevisionLevel="0" returnCode="0" status="SUCCESS" message="Success" schemaRevisionDate="2015-03-24">
  <instance uniquequery="file.device,logical.name=&quot;mss-abb-aejaljabelalifz-ra&quot;" query="" xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7">
    <file.device type="Structure">
      <CIName type="String">mss-abb-aejaljabelalifz-ra</CIName>
      <Type type="String">networkcomponents</Type>
      <Status type="String">In use</Status>
      <FriendlyName type="String">Jabel Ali Free Zone</FriendlyName>
      <Company type="String">ABB - MWAN</Company>
    </file.device>
    <file.networkcomponents type="Structure">
      <AccountNo type="String">1444016683</AccountNo>
    </file.networkcomponents>
    <attachments xsi:nil="true" />
  </instance>
  <instance uniquequery="file.device,logical.name=&quot;mss-abb-aldar-ra&quot;" query="" xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7">
    <file.device type="Structure">
      <CIName type="String">mss-abb-aldar-ra</CIName>
      <Type type="String">networkcomponents</Type>
      <Status type="String">In use</Status>
      <FriendlyName type="String">Al Dar AUH Main</FriendlyName>
      <Company type="String">ABB - MWAN</Company>
    </file.device>
    <file.networkcomponents type="Structure">
      <AccountNo type="String">1222229614</AccountNo>
    </file.networkcomponents>
    <attachments xsi:nil="true" />
  </instance>
 <instance uniquequery="file.device,logical.name=&quot;mss-abb-aldar-rb&quot;" query="" xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7">
    <file.device type="Structure">
      <CIName type="String">mss-abb-aldar-rb</CIName>
      <Type type="String">networkcomponents</Type>
      <Status type="String">In use</Status>
      <FriendlyName type="String">Al Dar-AUH-Backup</FriendlyName>
      <Company type="String">ABB - MWAN</Company>
    </file.device>
    <file.networkcomponents type="Structure">
      <AccountNo type="String">1222222368</AccountNo>
    </file.networkcomponents>
    <attachments xsi:nil="true" />
  </instance>
</RetrievedeviceListResponse>
```

I used the following code

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var authors = xdoc.Descendants("RetrievedeviceListResponse");

foreach (var author in authors)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",author.Name, author.Value);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem. Xml that you supplied is not valid. It doesn't have closing tag for RetrievedeviceListResponse. Can you load file? Or maybe you cannot read values?

Comment: have you looked into using `foreach(XElement`  examples on line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
   var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\TestCases\test.xml");
        foreach (var node in doc.Descendants().Where(x => "CIName Type Status FriendlyName AccountNo".Contains(x.Name.LocalName)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", node.Name.LocalName, node.Value));
        }
```

or pure linq:

```
    XDocument.Load(@"C:\TestCases\test.xml").Descendants().Where(x => "CIName Type Status FriendlyName AccountNo".Contains(x.Name.LocalName)).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", x.Name.LocalName, x.Value)));
```

Your not closing your "RetrievedeviceListResponse" in your xml too.

Comment: i will answer this, since it contains less number of lines:)

Comment: :) also you can replace the field string with a field string array in case you have similar fields that you don't want displayed.

Answer (score 2):

So maybe you could use something like this:

```
            const string @namespaceName = "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7";
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var authors = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("instance", @namespaceName));

            foreach (var author in authors)
            {
                string ciName = author.Descendants(XName.Get("CIName", namespaceName)).First().Value;
                string type = author.Descendants(XName.Get("Type", namespaceName)).First().Value;
                string frendlyName = author.Descendants(XName.Get("Type", namespaceName)).First().Value;
                string accountNo = author.Descendants(XName.Get("AccountNo", namespaceName)).First().Value;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", ciName, type, frendlyName, accountNo);
            }
```

You must use this namespaces if you want to use this code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: this will work but xela answered with less line of codes

Comment: it's ok. It's only important that you get your problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path); // Where path is the location of the XML file

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("RetrieveDeviceListResponse");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parent Node - {0}", nodes[i].InnerText);
    for(int j = 0; j < nodes[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child Node - {0}", nodes[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText);
    }
}
```

Does this do what you are looking for?

Comment: i need only  'CIName','Type','Status','FriendlyName','AccountNo' nodes values

Comment: XmlDocument is not recommend if you are above .NET 3.0. XDocument is the appropriate library.

Comment: This answer is not working ,nodes.Count is zero , i am using 4.5 version

Comment: Yeah sorry my comment for more for @KSdev, and since you are using 4.5 you should NOT be using XmlDocument object.

Comment: i was mainly using xdocument , for the time being i will invite any answers

Comment: You can use XmlDocument if you want.  Its an older API than XDocument, but supported.